# Error: function is not available for .Call() for package X

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm just starting to experiment with the Rcpp package, so please be patient with me.

I read the Rcpp vignettes and I've tried a few given examples in the Rcpp documentation. Now, I thought I'd start by wrapping some functions from the [GLFW](https://www.glfw.org/) libray, a library written in C.

So I thought I'd start with the function `glfwInit`. I wrote this simple cpp source file in a package named pixel to wrap it under the name `glfw_init`:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int glfw_init() {

  return(glfwInit());
}
```

I am working in RStudio, using the usual rinse and repeat cycle of generating documentation and building the package (I am using roxygen2).

The function is exported to R and the user space, so if I type `glfw_init` in the R console I get:

```
function() {
    .Call('_pixel_glfw_init', PACKAGE = 'pixel')
}
<bytecode: 0x5558ece6f398>
<environment: namespace:pixel>
```

But if I try to run it with `glfw_init()` and get the error:

```
Error in .Call("_pixel_glfw_init", PACKAGE = "pixel") : 
  "_pixel_glfw_init" not available for .Call() for package "pixel"
```

I feel I'm missing some minor setup detail for this to work... Any help is appreciated!

P.S.: As per Konrad's comment I am posting here the output I am getting in RStudio's build pane:

```
==> Rcpp::compileAttributes()

* Updated R/RcppExports.R

==> R CMD INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source pixel

g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R/" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/rmagno/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -fpic  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt  -c glfw.cpp -o glfw.o
* installing to library ‘/home/rmagno/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
* installing *source* package ‘pixel’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,-z,now -o pixel.so RcppExports.o glfw.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/rmagno/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-pixel/00new/pixel/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (pixel)
```

P.S.2: Here's my NAMESPACE:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(coords_rectangle)
export(coords_rectangular_lattice)
export(coords_segment)
export(coords_square)
export(display_matrix_int)
export(glfw_init)
export(lgl_matrix_to_coords_grid_segment)
export(lgl_matrix_to_coords_segment)
export(palette_for_quads)
```

P.S.3: After creating a new file `R/pixel.R`:

```
#' @useDynLib pixel, .registration = TRUE
#' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp
NULL
```

I get now this error when I try to generate the documentation:

```
==> Rcpp::compileAttributes()

* Updated R/RcppExports.R

==> devtools::document(roclets = c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

Updating pixel documentation
Loading pixel
Error in dyn.load(dllfile) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/rmagno/sci/code/R/pkg/pixel/src/pixel.so':
  /home/rmagno/sci/code/R/pkg/pixel/src/pixel.so: undefined symbol: glfwInit
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ... <Anonymous> -> load_dll -> library.dynam2 -> dyn.load
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Comment: Did you ensure that your Rcpp code was actually compiled? From the above this isn’t obvious: the glue code on the R side is generated, but that’s not directly related to the C++ library compilation.

Comment: Does you `NAMESPACE` file contain the required `importFrom(Rcpp,evalCpp)` and `useDynLib(pixel, .registration = TRUE)`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: please see my edit.

Comment: @RalfStubner: No! Indeed it has not. Should I do that manually? Or how do I tell roxygen2 to do it dynamically from now on?

Comment: With roxygen2 you can follow https://r-pkgs.org/src.html#cpp after adding `, .registration = TRUE` to `@useDynLib pixel`.

Comment: @RalfStubner Why the `importFrom` directive? The package code isn’t using `evalCpp`. On the other hand, the `@useDynLib` Roxygen tag is indeed needed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph See section "2.8 NAMESPACE" in the [Rcpp-package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf) vignette.

Comment: I am getting somewhere now, after @RalfStubner suggestions I am getting this about the function not being defined, please see my edit in the OP.

Comment: @RalfStubner Right, and as that section says it’s only needed if the R code actually uses Rcpp functionality. This isn’t the case here (nor in general).

Comment: This error indicates that you are not linking with the GLFW library. You probably need something like `PKG_LIBS = -lglfw` in `src/Makevars`. At least that's what `pkg-config --libs glfw3` tells me.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't know exactly why the `importFrom` is needed, but if I remove it from the package created with `Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton()` I get the error `Error in rcpp_hello_world() : function 'enterRNGScope' not provided by package 'Rcpp'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new error indicates that you didn’t link the C++ code against the GLFW library. You need to provide a `src/Makevars` file that adds the library to the `PKG_LIBS`. See [*Using Makevars*](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars) in the *Writing R Extensions* manual.

Comment: There is also quite a bit of documentation from Rcpp about how to link with an external library.  I think we generally reference RcppGSL as an example but there are _many_ others.

Comment: Thank you @konrad-rudolph and @dirk-eddelbuettel! I had to "Clean and Rebuild" to get it all working but it is now.

Comment: For someone else reading this here are the references I found useful: [Hadley's R packages | Section 13.4 Makefiles](https://r-pkgs.org/src.html#make) and [Dirk's Rcpp Package vignette | Section 2.7](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf).