# RcppEigen package error: not available for .Call() for package

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have an [RcppEigen package](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfexamplesinr) that successfully `Rcpp::sourceCpp()`s, `devtools::check()`s, and `devtools::document()`s, but I get the following error when I try to run a simple example:

```
Error in .Call("_pfexamplesinr_svolApproxLL", PACKAGE = "pfexamplesinr",  : 
  "_pfexamplesinr_svolApproxLL" not available for .Call() for package "pfexamplesinr"
```

The error is generated from the following minimal piece of code

```
devtools::install_github("tbrown122387/pfexamplesinr@cffe989")
numTime <- 3
numParts <- 500 # must agree with #define NP in likelihoods.cpp
u <- rnorm(numTime*(numParts+1))
params <- c(.9, 1, .1) # -1 < phi < 1, beta, sigma > 0
pfexamplesinr::svolApproxLL(rnorm(numTime), params, u)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58132832/error-function-is-not-available-for-call-for-package-x) suggests it might be a missing `PKG_LIBS` in `src/Makevars`, but [my `src/Makevars`](https://github.com/tbrown122387/pfexamplesinr/blob/master/src/Makevars) says

```
## With Rcpp 0.11.0 and later, we no longer need to set PKG_LIBS as there is
## no user-facing library. The include path to headers is already set by R.
#PKG_LIBS =
```

Comment: I had to add the three lines to `//' @export ; //' @useDynLib pfexamplesinr ; //' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp` (without the `;`) before `svolApproxLL` in the cpp file, After rerunning document & building again your code above runs and outputs one number

Comment: Yes.  And run `compileAttributes()` to get it into the R file, and run `roxygenize()` with full arguments to have the NAMESPACE rewritten.

Comment: The long and the short of it is that you could have used the `RcppEigen.package.skeleton()` (and/or the corresponding 'New Project -> Package w/ RcppEigen' in RStudio) but didn't so the skeleton you _did_ create did not ensure the actual loading of your package (object code) library.  Similar to a wrong `PKG_LIB` but as we no longer need that as you note, different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly *what* are you doing, and exactly *what* error do you get? It works here (apart from one warning):

```
edd@rob:~/git$ git clone git@github.com:eddelbuettel/pfexamplesinr.git
Cloning into 'pfexamplesinr'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 141, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (141/141), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (82/82), done.
remote: Total 141 (delta 65), reused 120 (delta 44), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (141/141), 46.75 KiB | 1.42 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (65/65), done.
edd@rob:~/git$ cd pfexamplesinr/
edd@rob:~/git/pfexamplesinr(master)$ install.r
* installing *source* package found in current working directory ...
* installing *source* package ‘pfexamplesinr’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
ccache g++  -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include'    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-unused -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-class-memaccess -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
ccache g++  -std=gnu++14 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include' -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include'    -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-unused -Wno-ignored-attributes -Wno-class-memaccess -c likelihoods.cpp -o likelihoods.o
In file included from likelihoods.cpp:2:
resamplers.h: In member function ‘void pf::resamplers::sys_hilb_resampler<nparts, dimx, num_hilb_bits, float_t>::resampLogWts(pf::resamplers::sys_hilb_resampler<nparts, dimx, num_hilb_bits, float_t>::arrayVec&, pf::resamplers::sys_hilb_resampler<nparts, dimx, num_hilb_bits, float_t>::arrayFloat&, const usvr&) [with long unsigned int nparts = 500; long unsigned int dimx = 1; long unsigned int num_hilb_bits = 5; float_t = double]’:
resamplers.h:1089:36: warning: ‘idx’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
 1089 |         tmpPartics[i] = sortedParts[idx];
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~^
ccache g++ -std=gnu++14 -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -o pfexamplesinr.so RcppExports.o likelihoods.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-pfexamplesinr/00new/pfexamplesinr/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (pfexamplesinr)
edd@rob:~/git/pfexamplesinr(master)$
```

I forked assuming it needed a fix; it doesn't look as if it requires one.

What may need adjusting is how you build the package and install it. I use some wrappers from my `littler` package, but a plain `R CMD INSTALL ...` will do too.  I now sent you a trivial pull request to suppress the warning on `idx`.

*Edit:* I see it now. You *started* from a plain package, not an Rcpp (or even RcppEigen package) so the NAMESPACE file is missing the `dynLib()` entry, among other things.

*Edit 2:*  Your `NAMESPACE` was insufficient.  The faster way is to just use the standard form as *e.g.* here

```
useDynLib(pfexamplesinr)
import(RcppEigen)
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)

## export all regularly named functions
## (but allow for private functions whose name starts with a dot).name <- function(...)
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

(The longer form generates the first three lines via `roxygen2`; I am sure you can add this.)

Once that is done,  your example runs:

```
edd@rob:~/git/pfexamplesinr(master)$ cat /tmp/test.R 
library(pfexamplesinr)
numTime <- 3
numParts <- 500
u <- rnorm(numTime*(numParts+1))
params <- c(.9, 1, .1) # -1 < phi < 1, beta, sigma > 0
svolApproxLL(rnorm(numTime), params, u)
edd@rob:~/git/pfexamplesinr(master)$ Rscript /tmp/test.R 
[1] -4.98311
edd@rob:~/git/pfexamplesinr(master)$
```

I'll amend my PR to add this.

Comment: thank you sir. I think I did start with the specialized skeleton function, but somewhere along the way I lost NAMESPACE for whatever reason. I'm not convinced I called the correct function to generate it, so I'll study up

Comment: It is actually surprisingly gnarly to get this right, and as you noticed the error message is not immediatly helpful. I recently expanded my helper script `kitten.r` (from the `littler` package I use a lot) to invoke the RcppArmadillo and RcppEigen helpers, but then that is still without roxygen2 support.  (And what @user20650 wrote in the comment is correct; I often still use the 'plain' approach for small packages.)  You are getting there with the package, let us know (hint: the rcpp-devel mailing is good too ;-) ) if we can help some more.